# set the value of the input field in the action of the form in django

Tags: django

I have created the modelforms with the name field and i want the retrieve the name  entered in the input field to be as a url in the django

forms.py

```
class githubform(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = github
        fields=['name']
```

model.py

```
class github(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

views.py

```
def github(request):
    gform = githubform(request.POST or None)
    if gform.is_valid():


        gform.save()
    return render(request,'formsapp/github.html',{'gform':gform})
```

github.html

```
<form method="post" action="https://api.github.com/users/{{ gform.data.name }}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ gform.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">signup</button>
  </form>
   <a href="">ccccc</a>
```

now i want the value of the input field entered by the user in place of gform.data.name and i am stuck in getting the value entered by the user into action url.

can anyone help me to sort it out

Answer (score 0):

delete method and action on form

```
<form id="form">
```

then submit with jquery

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function() {
    const value = $(input[name='name']).val()
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `https://api.github.com/users/${value}`,
        data: {
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()
        },
        success:function() {            
            console.log("success");
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});``
```